# How to validate a form against a custom user profile field?

Tags: 7, users, forms

I unsuccessfully tried https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms for forms validation so I am writing my own little validation module.

Basically, on node creation I want a **validation against a custom user profile field** (machine name: field_points). When the user enters on node creation more points then he has on his profile, an error message should appear.

Static validation against a number works just fine, but how can I access custom fields of the user object? Using devel, for some reason they don't show up in dpm($user).

[image: dpm($user)]

```
function custom2_form_contenttype_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
dpm($form);
//$form['field_points']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'] = 164;
$form['#validate'][] = 'custom2_form_contenttype_node_form_validate';
}

function custom2_form_contenttype_node_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
global $user;
dpm($user);
$profilePoints = $user->field_points;
$enteredPoints = $form_state['values']['field_points']['und']['0']['value'];
dpm($form['#validate']);
dpm($form_state);
if ($enteredPoints > $profilePoints) {
   form_set_error('field_points', '"You can only spend" .     $profilePoints . " //points."');
   }
```

}

EDIT: uploaded devel user screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your validate function

```
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);

$profilePoints = $user_fields->field_points['und'][0]['value'];
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. i get this message unfortunately: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_points in custom2_form_contenttype_node_form_validate() (line 25 of /Users/macmini/Sites/devdesktop/course/sites/all/modules/custom2/custom2.module). any idea why the custom fields of the user are not showing up? ive re-enabled devel, cleared cache...

Comment: use dpm to properly index your value. I followed from your code. When you load your user object using user_load function all your fields should be available then.

Comment: thx Shabir! the $user_fields = user_load($user->uid) did the trick. after this when i dpm($user_fields) it shows up and the profile points are accessible with $profilePoints = $user_fields->field_points['und'][0]['value'];

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code it is helpful for you

```
<?php

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_validation';
                                      }
                                                                }


function my_validation($node, $form, $form_state){

    if (!isset($form_state['values']['field_text']['und'][0]['field_text']['und'][0]['value']))
    {
        form_set_error('Text', 'Select text'); 
        }

}
```

Comment: hey Adi! Thx for the suggestion. Static form validation works - but i can't validate against a user profile field. I've added a screenshot to illustrate better what I mean

Comment: your field name??

Comment: there is a custom field (machine name: field_points) on the user profile. it does not show up when using devels dpm($user). why?

Comment: you use dsm against your from name or id then check it